# Should controller methods take arguments?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, conventions

Given that there is file selection widget on the view and controller need to handle event of selecting file, should I rather write controller method:

```
public void fileSelected(String filePath){
  //process filePath
}
```

or

```
public void fileSelected(){
  String filePath = view.getSelectedFilePath();
  //process filePath
}
```

The first approach seems to introduce less coupling between C and V: C don't know what exactly data does C need while handling given event.

But it requires creating a lot of verbose methods similar to `getSelectedFile` on V side.

On the other hand, second approach may lead to cluttered controller methods in more complex cases than in example (much more data to pass than just `filePath`).

From your own experience, which approach do you prefer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first approach is my favourite. The only difference is I would rather use an object (like Mario suggested) to pass arguments to the method. This way method's signature will not change when you add or remove some of the arguments. Less coupling is always good :)

One more thing:
If You want to try the second solution I recommend using a ViewFactory to remove view logic from the controller.

Answer (score 6):

The first approach is the way to go;

```
public void fileSelected(String filePath){
  //process filePath
}
```

The `Controller` should not care about how the `View` looks like or how it's implemented. It gets much clearer for the developer as well, when creating/updating the view, to know what an action in the controller wants. Also it makes it easier for method overloading.

Though, I don't know really how `String filePath = view.getSelectedFilePath();` would work. Are we talking about parsing the View code/markup?

> On the other hand, second approach may lead to cluttered controller methods in more complex cases than in example (much more data to pass than just filePath).

That's when you would create a View Model class (let's say we name it `MyViewModel`) to store all the properties that you need to send (may it be 10 properties) and then pass that in the action: `fileSelected(MyViewModel model)`. That's how it's intended to be used and what the *`ModelBinder`'s in asp.net mvc are there to help you with.

Comment: In answer to your question: let's assume we are passing selected file path in filesystem (I updated question). I choosed file paths in example to avoid unnecessary discussion about whether View should know about classes like `File` etc which is not relevant to my question.

Comment: Yeah, your arguments are reasonable. But one additional disadvantage of this approach is cluttering method signatures in more complex cases (more than just one thing to pass). Controller methods with 10 arguments doesn't seem especially clean. How to handle this issue?

Comment: @PiotrSobczyk I'm not quite following you on the `File` class and the View knowing about it. Why would the View need to know about it?

Comment: @PiotrSobczyk To your second comment: I would create a ViewModel class  (let's say we name it `MyViewModel`) to store all the properties that I need to send (may it be 10 properties) and then I would pass that in the action: `fileSelected(MyViewModel model)`. That's how it's intended to be used and what the *`ModelBinder`'s in  asp.net mvc are there to help you with.

Comment: Should there be one specialized ViewModel for each View-Controller interaction (eg. selecting file, submitting the form, checking the checkbox etc... there may be a lot of it) or should there be just one ViewModel to handle all of these interactions (passed to every controller method)? The first option may lead class explosion in more complex cases, the second option we have one big object representing all the view state - so why just don't get this data directly from view? All in all I'd prefer the first option if I'd decided to go that way.

Comment: @PiotrSobczyk What are you developing in? Asp.net?

Comment: I'm developing in Java but my question is language and technology agnostic. I'm asking about MVC pattern in general

Comment: @PiotrSobczyk Ok, even though MVC is just a pattern, it's implemented differently in different techniques. Unfortunately, I don't know much about how it's implemented in java techniques. But I know that in ASP.NET MVC-pattern there are model binders that makes it easier to use a view model (like I described before). But in general you would create a view model for each purpose, but you could create a more generic one as well. Maybe work with inheritance if there's shared properties between models. I guess it's better to ask a question more related to java MVC.

Comment: Allright. Thanks for your explainations and effort that you put in your answers. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to look at this from a step back.

> Worry less about how it gets in, and be more concerned with *validation* and *error raising*.

Tomorrow, your requirements could change and demand that you source the information via a different architectural approach.  You could refactor the setup of [inputs / an input object] into a base controller class - or one of several classes for different controller domains.

If you focus on proper validation, whether within the controller (scrubbing) or outside of it (unit tests), then you perform more thorough decoupling though [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the first approach. It's reusable and separates concerns. Even if the method of getting the filePath in the future were to change, it won't affect your method's functionality.